# How to get Sql Record with out any reference on given example

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

I have two table as table1 and table 2 as [image]

I want one table3 structure as

[image]

I dont have any of the reference between upper two tables.

1.Is it possible in single select statement?

Or

2.Required looping for that.

What I have tried is

```
    select E.EmpID,E.FName,E.LName,C.CityName,E.Salary,DOJ,
    case
    when E.Salary > 0 and E.Salary < 30001 then 'Trainee'
    when E.Salary > 30001 and E.Salary < 60001 then 'Jr. Developer'
    when E.Salary > 60001 and E.Salary < 150001 then 'Sr. Developer'
    when E.Salary > 150001 and E.Salary < 180001 then 'Project Lead'
    when E.Salary > 180001 and E.Salary < 250001 then 'Project Manager'
    else '' end  as Designation 
    from Emp_Master as E inner join City_Master as C
    on E.CityID = C.CityId
```

which I think is totally wrong

**Please answer me Providing example**

Comment: Please tag your question appropriately.  Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: It is possible with a single select if, you can divide the Salary in the first table.

Comment: @PeterRing can you bprovide me with example

Comment: The problem you have is badly designed database. You should never store more than one value in a field, which you are now doing with the salary range. If you split that into separate fields (SalaryFrom, SalaryTo), then it's a lot more simple to query the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to cast the string into two VARCHARs in order to get the JOIN you want:

```
SELECT table2.EmpId, table2
    .FName, table2.LName, 
    table2.CityID, table2.
    DOJ, table2.salary, 
    table1.Designation
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.
    salary BETWEEN CAST(LEFT(
                    table1.salary, 
                    CHARINDEX('>', 
                        table1.salary
                    ) - 1) AS INT)
        AND CAST(RIGHT(table1.
                    salary, LEN(
                        table1.salary
                    ) - CHARINDEX('>'
                        , table1.
                        salary)) AS INT
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your first table, so it contains a minimum and maximum salary.  Putting a rule in as a string does not work well in SQL.

Once you make this change, then you can approach the query in several ways, such as a correlated subquery:

```
select t2.*,
       (select t1.designation
        from table1 t1
        where t2.salary between minsalary and maxsalary
       ) as designation
from table2 t2;
```

Comment: How should i get min and max salary in between statement? Need single query

Comment: @MiteshJain . . . You should structure the data correctly for your problem.  Having a string to represent the ranges is a bad idea.